# Sempre é preciso chamar o construtor da classe pai na classe filha?

Tags: php

criei duas classes uma classe pai que tem um construtor onde tenho que passar alguns argumentos, e uma classe filha que herda essa classe pai que criei, porém na classe filha eu não fiz o construtor e nem usei o:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Mas ao instânciar a classe filha da erro, se eu não passar os argumentos no cabeçalho dela, e quando passo os argumentos ela funciona normal e eu consigo usar todos os métodos da classe pai.

Então cheguei a conclusão que, não é preciso chamar o construtor da classe pai dentro da classe filha, a não ser que a classe filha tenha um construtor própio, ai eu teria que passar seus respectivos argumentos e os argumentos da classe pai através do **parent::__construct();**.

Minha conclusão está correta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É isso mesmo, se você está estendendo o comportamento do pai você obrigatoriamente precisa passar os parâmetros exigidos pelo mesmo, caso você não precise de novos comportamentos no construtor não é necessário chamar o construtor do pai. Chamar o construtor do pai indica que vc irá realizar uma sobrescrita na construção do objeto, seja para adicionar, remover ou alterar o comportamento do modo como o objeto é construído.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, essa dúvida me veio aqui porque no nosso sistema que já é antigo... costumamos montar as classe filhas chamando o construtor da classe pai esse construtor é do controller do CodeIgniter. Estou fazendo um novo projeto e não chamei o construtor da classe pai porque não precisei modifica-lo e funcionou, ai fiquei com essa dúvida, valeu mesmo.